# How to read multiple lines separately using Scanner class from a file?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have saved a text file on my computer with name Playlist.txt, and saved two song paths in it. It's working fine if there is only one song, it's playing it well. But when I'm adding more than 1 song paths, it is reading the most recent path added that is the last song path added. So how can I make Scanner object reading lines separately, and it should play both the songs.

```
if (ae.getSource() == open_Playlist) {
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    int i = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        try {
            File playList_File = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(playList_File);  
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = sc.nextLine();
                mp3 = new MP3Player(new File(data));
                mp3.setShuffle(true);

                System.out.println(data);
            }

            sc.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have to _read_ the playlist looks OK; if there are multiple lines in the playlist file, it should be able to read them.  Can you show us the code you are using to _write_ songs to the playlist? It sounds suspiciously as if you are _overwriting_ the playlist file, rather than adding to it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I didn't add that functionality so far, I was just testing if user browse to a already created text file(playlist.txt), then will it function well or not. I created that file with Notepad and added two song paths randomly. Like this 


E:\NCS Songs\10convert.com_Calli-Boom-Revenge-Bass-Boosted_SAWz1nloykI.mp3 
E:\NCS Songs\10convert.com_Danell-Arma-Oligarch_yhOYPGGTnIo.mp3

Comment: OK, then...  next thing I'd suspect is the usage of the  `MP3Player` class.  You're creating a new `MP3Player` instance for each song, and overwriting the old instance each time, which will leave you with just one `MP3Player` instance: the one created for the last song.  Is it possible you should be creating just one `MP3Player` and then calling an "add song" method on it for each song?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I don't think that's possible, I've done the same thing with even when I'm browsing a new song from my computer. 

See : https://pastebin.com/QKEfFt7h

Comment: Yes, but that's to play _one_ song, or at least to start just _one_ playing.  Now,  what happens if, while one song is already playing, you browse another song? I'm guessing the old song stops playing and the new one starts... Same thing happens when you start several songs in a row as you read a playlist.  There's probably some API on the `MP3Player` class you should be using to use to load up a whole playlist,  rather than creating a new player for every single song.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I just tried with 2 more variables, then they're holding one song by one variable. And I can play all songs by providing diff variables, but how can I do that with one single variable.

Comment: @KevinAnderson can you please demonstrate a bit, I'm getting what you're saying but seems not easy to implement.

Comment: Maybe you can construct an `MP3Player` instance with a `File[]`, or a `List<File>`, or there's a `setPlaylist` method that takes a `File[]` or `List<File>`, or an `addSong` to add songs individually to the player's playlist.  But you'll never be able to know for sure unless you find some documentation (or even source code) for the `MP3Player` class.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yeah I also thought about static List<File>, and yes there are methods to addToPlaylist , but no specified source code is there for this JarFile. I'll definitely look out for List stuff, but if that doesn't happen well. I'll use JDBC with Primary key and Radnom generator to shufle songs randomly from DB. Anyways thanks for providing me such solutions.